# Characteristic of residue field in a Dedekind domain.

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, dedekind-domain, ramification, positive-characteristic

Let's consider a Dedekind domain $A$ with field of fractions $K$. Let $L$ be a finite Galois extension of $K$ and $B$ the integral closure of $A$ in $L$. Let $\mathfrak{p}\subset A$ be a non-zero prime ideal and $\mathfrak{P} \subset B$ a prime lying above $\mathfrak{p}$. Let $L'$ be the inertia field of $\mathfrak{P}$ and let $\mathfrak{P}':=\mathfrak{P}\cap L'$. Denote by $k(\mathfrak{P})$, $k(\mathfrak{P}')$, $k(\mathfrak{p})$ the respective residue fields.

In class we proved that $k(\mathfrak{P}')$ is the maximal separable subextension of $k(\mathfrak{P})/k(\mathfrak{p})$ and a step of the proof says that the extension $k(\mathfrak{P})/k(\mathfrak{P'})$ is purely inseparable. But to say this I should know that the characteristic of the residue field is positive. How do I know this? Does it follow from some properties of Dedekind domains? Is it some known fact? In my notes there's nothing about it.

The proposition in a more elaborated form) is stated as Thm. 24 on p. 292 of *Commutative Algebra I* by Zariski and Samuel ([pdf](http://www.math.purdue.edu/~egoins/seminar/zariski-samuel.pdf)), where he also says that the characteristic of the residue field is $p>0$, but I don't see why.

Comment: it sounds like this all geared for the case where $K$ is a number field and $R = \mathcal O_K$, but i'm not entirely sure.

Comment: No, K is not necessarily a number field, it's the quotient field of an arbitrary Dedekind domain.

Comment: You probably need some stronger condition. For number field, the quotient is always a finite field extension of a finite field which means any finite extension is always a separable extension. There should be some assumption on $A$(i.e. $|A/p|$ cardinality or residue field degree).